# How to hyphenate in a \synt{} with the syntax package?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, syntax

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\synt{blahblah-blahblah} blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `blahblah-blahblah` is not hyphenated. Clearly, `-` is not allowed as a hyphenation point in `\synt`. How can I make it so it hyphenates? Like this:

[image]

A search for "hyphen" in the `syntax` package [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdwtools) did not show anything relevant.

Comment: Can you add a link to the manual of the package? I did not find it on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/topic/syntax).

Comment: You can't the docu says "Breaking of a \synt object across lines is forbidden".

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have updated my answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh that's sad :( Maybe I will have to resort to `\langle` and `\textit` then ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492600/how-to-hyphenate-in-a-synt-with-the-syntax-package#comment1243865_492600), the document clearly says that

> Breaking of a `\synt` object across lines is forbidden.

on page 16. Therefore, I resorted to rolling out my own one:

```
% breakable \synt
\newcommand*{\bsynt}[1]{{\syntleft{#1\/}\syntright}}
```